# Is it possible to get the value of a form in the same page with or without javascript enabled?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

The code i'm trying to use in jsonoff.php as below :

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['myname'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['myname'])) {
    $myname = $_POST['myname'];
    echo $myname;
    } else {
        echo 'Please type a name';
    }
    exit; //without this, if javascript enabled there will be two times page content.
  }
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="notification"></div>

<form action="" method="POST">

    <input type="text" name="myname" id="myname">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"  id="submit" >

</form>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function(){

  $('#submit').click(function(e){

       var myname = $('#myname').val();
       $.post('jsonoff.php', {myname : myname} , function(data){

        $('#notification').html(data);

      });

     e.preventDefault();
  });
 });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Problem with the `exit;` line is that if users disable javascript then php takes over the job and with this `exit;` it outputs just the notification div and doesn't display the form.

What i'm trying to achieve is that other than the page refresh the result/display will be the same and in the same page for both javascript on or javascript off, so that user will have a same experience whether they disable javascript or not.

Comment: why the exit; is required here ?

Comment: ..display the form (again) before the `exit()` ?

Comment: @WordpressCoder try the code without exit; and see what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a workaround, yes its quite possible, write a boolean flag on that `$.post` so that it can discern a `jquery post`, or a normal submission:

```
$.post(document.URL, {myname : myname, fromjs: true} , function(data){
                                        ^^ this one
    $('#notification').html(data);

});

e.preventDefault();
```

Then in PHP:

```
<?php

$output = '';
if (isset($_POST['myname'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['myname'])) {
    $myname = $_POST['myname'];
    echo $myname;
    $output = $myname;
    } else {
        $output = 'Please type a name';
    }
    if(isset($_POST['fromjs'])) { // if this is sent in JS, trigger an exit
        exit; //without this, if javascript enabled there will be two times page content.
    }
    // if JS is disabled, this will never execute. because index fromjs doesn't exist
  }
?>
```

Notification inside the disabled JS:

```
<div id="notification">
<?php if($output != '' && !isset($_POST['fromjs'])) {
    echo $output;
} ?>
</div>
```

Final Product:

```
<?php
$output = '';
if (isset($_POST['myname'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['myname'])) {
    $myname = $_POST['myname'];
    $output = $myname;
    } else {
        $output = 'Please type a name';
    }
    if(isset($_POST['fromjs'])) { // if this is sent in JS, trigger an exit
        echo $output;
        exit; //without this, if javascript enabled there will be two times page content.
    }
    // if JS is disabled, this will never execute. because index fromjs doesn't exist
  }
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="notification">
<?php if($output != '' && !isset($_POST['fromjs'])) {
    echo $output;
} ?>
</div>

<form action="" method="POST">

    <input type="text" name="myname" id="myname">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"  id="submit" >

</form>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function(){

  $('#submit').click(function(e){

       var myname = $('#myname').val();
       $.post(document.URL, {myname : myname, fromjs: true} , function(data){

            $('#notification').html(data);

        });

        e.preventDefault();
  });
 });

</script>
```

Comment: Nice workaround. but if JS is disabled how do i put the notification in the notification div? i can echo the div but then if JS is enabled it will be like `<div id="notification"><div id="notification">The feedback</div></div>`

Comment: Also should i do it this way for showing form validation notification or there are any better ways security wise and such?

Comment: @user1906399 well, regarding the notification, you can just echo on the markup as well, just use a that boolean flag again inside the div, regarding validations, just make sure always check the input both client and server side

Comment: @user1906399 check my revision, this should give the idea of from my previous comment

Comment: @your modified code will give output two times if javascript is disabled, first from the `echo $myname` and second from inside notification div

Comment: @user1906399 yes, you just need to ditch the `echo`, since the real objective it to put all notifications inside the notifications div, just erase that one :)

Comment: Problem is if you don't echo, if javascript is enabled nothing will happen , because without echo there is no feedback to put inside notification div

Comment: @user1906399 there check the revisionb

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when you use the exit function in php code it is exiting the script right at that point not event displaying the notification div. It just display the message which is been echo before exit function. So, either user your php code at the end of the page or just remove the exit function.

And also it will not give the same affect that javascript was giving. Because when you are using the javascript code it is not submitting the form to a same page, it is using ajax and not refereshing the whole page. But, if javascript is disable then the form is submitted to itself and content of all the page is refresh again.

Comment: If javascript is enabled you have to put that exit; otherwise feedback will be the whole page again, and the end result will be the two times of the original content.

Comment: When you are using javascript it is not seeing it as a form